# Using Partial Limit

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \cos(\pi/2\cos(x))/x^2$$

I tried to evaluate the limit this way,

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \cos(\pi/2\cdot1)/x^2$$  since $\cos0=1$

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \cos(\pi/2\cdot1)/x^2=\lim_{x \to 0} 0/x^2$$

Now apply L'Hospital's Rule twice,

$$\lim_{x \to 0} 0/2(x)=\lim_{x \to 0} 0/2=0$$

So,this way the answer is zero.

Can you please explain where am I doing wrong?

I will be thankful for help!

Comment: You can't simply plug 0 into parts. Take $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac xx$ for example. Plugging 0 into the numerator implies the limit should be 0, but clearly the limit is 1.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt But,in some of the questions we do replace 'x' by the constant values such that it simplifies to a non zero number.Why are we allowed to do that?

Comment: Limit rules and continuous functions satisfy $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt please go through this conversation once https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q2h1766346p11567701

Comment: "The only thing that I need to keep in mind is that the expression doesn't become indeterminate." This is vague, and also the reason we have clear limit rules to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When both the numerator and denominator are zero, you have to differentiate both of them to obtain the correct limit. You can't straightly make the numerator $0$. Think about it, if you have
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{2x}{3x}$$
, and you make the numerator zero and differentiate the denominator, you will get zero, which clearly isn't correct.

What I suggest is that you differentiate both the numerator and the denominator to get 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\pi\sin(x)\sin(\pi/2\cos(x))}{4x}$$
Now differentiate again, and you get
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\pi\left[\cos(x)\sin(\pi/2\cos(x))-\pi/2\sin(x)(\cos(\pi/2\cos(x)))\right]}{4}=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Comment: Thanks So Much! Please go through this once https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q2h1766346p11567701 I just want to know how to decide which 'x' are safe to replace by their constant values?

Comment: Nikolas did a pretty good job explaining when it is safe to replace the values. Yes, when the denominator becomes zero, you don't want to replace the value. In this question, the denominator is zero, so you can't just replace the value. You would instead do L'Hospital or some other manipulations as presented in other answers posted here.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Compose Taylor series
$$\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+O\left(x^4\right)$$
$$\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2}   \cos (x)\right)=\sin \left(\frac{\pi  }{4}x^2+O\left(x^4\right)\right)$$ The next step is simple.

Answer (score 2):

Using $\frac{1-\cos(x)}{2}=\sin^2(x/2)$ and $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin(t)}{t}=1$, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\cos\left(\frac\pi2 \cos(x)\right)}{x^2}&=\frac{\sin\left(\pi \sin^2(x/2)\right)}{x^2}\\\\
&=\frac\pi4\underbrace{\left(\frac{\sin(x/2)}{x/2}\right)^2}_{\to1\,\,\text{as}\,\,x\to0}\underbrace{\left(\frac{\sin\left(\pi \sin^2(x/2)\right)}{\pi\sin^2(x/2)}\right)}_{\to 1\,\,\text{as}\,\,x\to0}\\\\
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we find that

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos\left(\frac\pi2 \cos(x)\right)}{x^2}=\frac\pi4$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  And Happy New Year! ;-)